# Plotly: Scatter plot with dropdown menu and color by group

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to make a scatter plot with 2 dropdown menus that select a data column (from a pandas data frame) to be plotted for x and y-axis, but I'm also wanting the points to be colored by a third categorical variable that is fixed (no dropdown needed for this one).

So far, I've been able to create the scatterplot correctly with functional dropdown menus [thanks to another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69510612/plotly-scatter-plot-with-dropdown-menu-to-change-data-and-calculated-annotation), but I don't know how to colorize it by a third variable. Here's the code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips().select_dtypes(['number']) # drop non numeric columns

fig = go.Figure(
go.Scatter(
    x=df['total_bill'],
    y=df['tip'],
    hovertemplate='x: %{x} <br>y: %{y}',
    mode="markers"))
fig.update_layout(
updatemenus=[
    {
        "buttons": [
            {
                "label": f"x - {x}",
                "method": "update",
                "args": [
                    {"x": [df[x]]},
                    {"xaxis": {"title": x}},
                ],
            }
            for x in cols
        ]
    },
    {
        "buttons": [
            {
                "label": f"y - {x}",
                "method": "update",
                "args": [
                    {"y": [df[x]]},
                    {"yaxis": {"title": x}}
                ],
            }
            for x in cols
        ],
        "y": 0.9,
    },
],
margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 25, "b": 0},
height=700)
fig.show()
```

Ultimately, I want the same scatterplot, but for points to be colorized by "Category". I can do this using plotly express, but without dropdown menus very easily:

```
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", color="smoker", trendline="ols")
fig.show()
```

Anyone has an idea of how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned below, I was able to find a solution for this by creating a new column with hexadecimal color codes corresponding to categorical levels in another column:

```
dfx = px.data.tips()
# create list of columns to iterate over for buttons
cols = dfx.columns.values.tolist()
# make list of default plotly colors in hex
plotly_colors=[
                '#1f77b4',  # muted blue
                '#ff7f0e',  # safety orange
                '#2ca02c',  # cooked asparagus green
                '#d62728',  # brick red
                '#9467bd',  # muted purple
                '#8c564b',  # chestnut brown
                '#e377c2',  # raspberry yogurt pink
                '#7f7f7f',  # middle gray
                '#bcbd22',  # curry yellow-green
                '#17becf'   # blue-teal
              ]
# create dictionary to associate colors with unique categories
color_dict = dict(zip(dfx['smoker'].unique(),plotly_colors))
# map new column with hex colors to pass to go.Scatter()
dfx['hex']= dfx['smoker'].map(color_dict)
#initialize scatter plot
fig = go.Figure(
    go.Scatter(
        x=dfx['total_bill'],
        y=dfx['tip'],
        text=dfx['smoker'],
        marker=dict(color=dfx['hex']),
        mode="markers"
    )
) 
# initialize dropdown menus
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": f"x - {x}",
                    "method": "update",
                    "args": [
                        {"x": [dfx[x]]},
                        {"xaxis": {"title": x}},
                    ],
                }
                for x in cols
            ]
        },
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": f"y - {x}",
                    "method": "update",
                    "args": [
                        {"y": [dfx[x]]},
                        {"yaxis": {"title": x}}
                    ],
                }
                for x in cols
            ],
            "y": 0.9,
        },
    ],
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 25, "b": 0},
    height=700
)
fig.show()
```

[image: Final scatterplot with points colored by categorical column, "smoker"]

Answer (score 1):

If you understand that you want to use the size column for color coding, you can do so by specifying that column as the marker color.

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(
    x=dfs['total_bill'],
    y=dfs['tip'],
    hovertemplate='x: %{x} <br>y: %{y}',
    mode="markers",
    marker=dict(color=df['size']) # update
))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This solution works great, but only for numerical columns such as df['size'] as in this case.  My application involves colorized by a categorical variable like df['smoker'].  When I try using 'smoker' in this code, it returns that the variable must be a named color, number, or list.  Any ideas here?

Comment: If you pass in a numerical value, it will convert it to a color, so I think it is possible to either add a new numerical column that matches the category value, or replace it with a numerical value using [rename_categories()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#renaming-categories).